# Use properties of definition of a vector space to prove that $0v = \mathbf{0}$ for any $v$

Tags: vector-spaces, solution-verification

My proof is:

There exists $-v$ such that $\mathbf{0} = -v + v = \mathbf{0}$;
Then $\mathbf{0} = -v + v = [(-1)+1] v = 0 v$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another proof:

Observe
\begin{align}
0\cdot v = (0+0)\cdot v = 0\cdot v + 0\cdot v.
\end{align}
Subtracting from both sides yields
\begin{align}
\mathbf{0} = 0\cdot v - 0\cdot v = 0\cdot v+0\cdot v - 0\cdot v = 0\cdot v  + \mathbf{0} = 0\cdot v.
\end{align}

Note: I have used $\mathbf{0}$ to denote the zero element in the vector space and $0$ to denote the zero element in the scalar field.

Comment: Thx for another proof.

Comment: It should be noted that sometimes you might not have additive inverse for a given algebraic structure, i.e. not every $v$ has a $-v$ . But you still have a zero element, which then the above proof will work.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on those situations?

Answer (score 0):

( Here ⋅ denotes multiplication ,  + denotes addition operation. )
We can proof it by a simple equation..
$(1+0)\cdot v= 1\cdot v + 0\cdot v $ and  $1\cdot v = v $

by definition in the vector space.
$(1+0)\cdot v=1\cdot v=v $ then
$v=v+0\cdot v$
Again in the vector space definition $0(\text{vector})+ v = v$
Then $0\cdot v $ must be zero vector

Comment: This would be easier to read with MathJax. Here is a list of tips for MathJax use : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference